# VS add on Test scribe - modifying report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, microsoft-test-manager

I'm new to Microsoft Test Manager, but have found a way to generate test plans and doing testing relatively efficiently. Now, I'm trying to learn how to use Test Scribe.

I need the reports to contain passed tests, together with test steps. Right now I'm able to create reports from "plan" with test steps included, and reports from "test" with success/no success included - but how do I get both? I sort of want the data from the "test plan summary" report, containing "step successful" / "step not successful".

Does anyone know how to do that..?

Comment: I've searched the web a bit more and found that this is actually by design. If anyone has a brilliant solution for how to get the result I'm after anyway, please post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to amke some changes in the template of the summary report file generated.
Follow the URL [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shair/2011/10/16/how-to-change-test-scribe-template/)